# Eclipse refactoring methods (specifically extract method) have stopped working

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have been using eclipse indigo happily for android development for a while.  In the last few days it has stopped refactoring.  I have tried a project clean and of course restarting eclipse.

I have also tried renaming the org.eclipse.core.resources directory as suggested here: -

http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/

Any ideas what I could do? Thanks!

Comment: "Stopped refactoring" - could you clarify? Which refactors fail, and exactly how? Any error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  Extract Method is the one that I'm having trouble with, rename and creating methods / variables from usage are working properly

Comment: Is the Extract Method menu item disabled, or can you select it? What happens if you select it? What about using the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I have tried using the menu and the alt+shift+m shortcut.  Nothing happens at all, no error either.  The menu item is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried starting Eclipse with `-clean`? http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm

Comment: Gave it a try, but unfortunately the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has now randomly started working again.  If I find the reason I'll post it here for googlers!

Answer (score 0):

I get this occasionally. It usually happens when you install (or update) and plugin and that plugin has a key binding the same as alt-shift-m (or cmd-alt-m on OSX). You need to go into your eclipse preferences and change the key bindings.

Under preferences go to General -> Keys. Then search for the shortcut in the bindings field. You will need to delete the binding and add your preferred one back in.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a key binding issue, I've tried using the menus and the same thing happens (i.e. nothing)

Comment: If there are no key binding clashes then I'm not sure. Sorry.